# Ist die Benutzung von "Platz" anstatt "Ort" eine Entlehnung aus dem Englischen?

Tags: meaning, synonym, english

Ich lese in letzter Zeit immer öfter Aussagen wie z.B. "Dies ist der schönste Platz der Welt".
Ich frage mich, ob der Verfasser dieses Satzes nicht eher "Dies ist der schönste Ort der Welt" sagen wollte und zu sehr vom englischen "place" bzw. dessen Benutzung "This is the most beautiful place in the world" beeinflusst wurde.

Meiner Meinung nach gilt das Wort "Platz" nur im Sinne von z.B. Dorfplatz etc. Stimmt das?

Comment: Nun, ich glauber nicht, dass Bernhard von Bülow, der 1897 für das Deutsche Reich einen "Platz an der Sonne" forderte, einfach nur ein paar hundert Quadratmeter Pflastersteine in Afrika oder Asien verlegen wollte.

Comment: Weiteres Gegenbeispiel: Herrman Löns (1924), [Der schönste Platz](http://www.zeno.org/nid/20005355192).

Comment: Auch im Niederlädischen benutzen wir *plaats* (Platz) und nur ganz selten *oord* (Ort) und *Platz*, wie Dorfplatz usw., ist *plein*. Aber *Platz* ist nicht nur von der letzten Zeit. Das wurde schon viel früher in der Bedeutung von *Ort* benutzt.

Answer (score 6):

Mal abgesehen davon, dass es fast unmöglich ist zu sagen, ob ein Wort nur in einem Sinn „gilt“, ist diese Verwendung von Platz gar nicht unüblich.

Duden gibt als eine Bedeutung von Platz

> Stelle, Ort (für etwas oder an dem sich etwas befindet)

an und führt dieses Beispiel auf:

> die bedeutendsten Plätze für den Überseehandel sind Hamburg und Bremen

---

Beim Satz „Dies ist der schönste Platz der Welt“ würde ich allerdings schon sagen, dass diese Verwendung nicht idiomatisch ist und eigentlich „Ort“ zu erwarten wäre. Irgendwie falsch ist es aber auch nicht.

Answer (score 5):

Das deutsche [Platz](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Platz) ist wie das englische *[place](https://www.etymonline.com/word/place)* eine Entlehnung aus dem Latein (*platea*) und schon im Mittelhochdeutschen vorhanden. Der englische Begriff ist eventuell über das Altfranzösische *place* entstanden. Das deutsche Wort sei direkt entlehnt, beziehungweise soll schon im Gotischen vorhanden gewesen sein (*plapja*).

Die verchiedenen Bedeutungen haben sich aber in unseren Sprachen nie sehr unterschieden, so dass auch die heutige Verwendung direkt auf ihre gemeinsame Herkunft zurückgeführt werden kann.

Answer (score 3):

"Platz" wird durchaus aus als abstrakte "Lokation" verwendet. Ein Handwerker räumt seine Werkzeuge sorgfältig jeweils an den richtigen Platz ein. Deutschland wollte einen "Platz an der Sonne" und meinte damit einen Platz wie im Klassement eines Sportwettbewerbs.

Aber im Sinne einer bestimmten Stadt oder Restauration ist "Das ist ein hübscher Platz" eindeutig ein neuerer Anglizismus. Es wäre ein zu grosser Zufall, wenn da die typische Wendung "this is a nice place" nicht Ursprung gewesen wäre.

Comment: "Das ist ein hübscher Platz" für eine Stadt oder ein Wirtshaus fühlt sich für mich auf Deutsch auch nach wie vor schief an. Man könnte es sagen, wenn "Platz" sich auf eine bestimmte Stelle z.B. in der Natur bezieht, oder von mir aus auch auf eine bestimmte Stelle in einer Stadt, aber "Stelle" (oder eben "Platz") hier immer im Sinne von "direkte, sichtbare, physische Umgebung". Darum passt es nicht z.B. für eine ganze Stadt, da diese ja nie in toto sichtbar sein wird.